# Why did my asynchronous test in react not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing

Im testing a react component with jest and the react testing library (newest versions) and i dont get the asynchron tests to work. I assume its a syntax problem. The component gets rendert correctly, and the fetch (useEffect) also seems to work due to the fact that the time out works.

```
test('renders asynchron', async () => {
   renderComp(); //renders component
   
   await waitFor(() => expect(screen.findByTestId('testid')).toBeInTheDocument()); //dont work
   await screen.findByTestId('testid'); //same

   setTimeout(() => {
      expect(screen.findByTestId('testid')).toBeInTheDocument(); //this works
   }, 100);

});
```

Also i got the same issue if i expect an element after an button click.

Comment: Can you add your `renderComp` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because following arrow function is not awaitable:

```
() => expect(screen.findByTestId('testid')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

you must Define inner function async and await for.

Comment: thank you! but random tried every syntax i could found